Are there any online resources to a nationwide database to confirm contractual agreements of which I am a party?
I have recently encountered some potentially disturbing information regarding my name qualifying and being subject to a situation of which I was completely unaware. There are obvious legal implications to what I'd seen but I'm unable to find the information anywhere on the company's website. This took me down a rabbit hole to figure out if/where else my name is under any legal obligations that I don't know about. Come to find out, I am denied access to any of my own information whatsoever. I don't have any money so I can't pay for what I'm looking for. But since it's MY information, that should not be a requirement. And I've searched through various government websites as well, which has proven to be absolutely worthless. Is there anybody with advice as to how I can properly navigate this problem? Because it's about to become an issue for the whole country if I can't remedy this situation...

Language in this question emphasizing the idea of obligations attaching to a person's name gives me a whiff of sov-cit

@alexg Either that or someone thinking that data brokers scraping their data implies some sort of contract or obligation

Can you explain "Because it's about to become an issue for the whole country if I can't remedy this situation"?

@alexg https://law.stackexchange.com/users/75648/jeremy-cancelo All-caps first name "JEREMY Cancelo" also gives me those vibes

"...regarding my name qualifying and being subject to a situation of which I was completely unaware." I'm interested in an answer because I was just notified that I am qualified to upgrade my windows and I'm concerned for the country.  In all seriousness, I don't see a legit legal question in this, and / or it needs more detail

Laws and regulations in general could be seen as *non-*contractual legal obligations, as they have legal implications which could apply to you even if you're not previously aware of them? But that's unrelated to personal information. This question needs an example to clarify it.

Frame challenge:
In general and by definition, it's not possible to be a party to a contract of which you are "completely unaware". There are formalities for contract formation which require your active participation. You need to have either knowingly accepted an offer, or knowingly made an offer which was accepted. You also need to have intended the contract to be legally binding. If any of these elements are missing then there is no enforceable contract.
The only scenario I can think of which might be an exception is that you appointed an agent to whom you gave a general authority to enter into contracts on your behalf (as opposed to authority to enter into a specific contract which you know about). For example, this might happen if you gave someone a general power of attorney to manage your finances for you. It would then be possible that the agent could have entered you into a contract without informing you. However in that scenario the agent would owe you fidicuairy duties and you can ask them to provide you with details of the contract.
As pointed out in Dale M's answer there is no database of private contracts, nor would it be practical for one to exist. Consider that a contract is formed every time you buy something from a shop, take a bus, use a paid car park, go to the cinema, etc. The economy would grind to a halt if all of these had to be registered in a database.
In the united-kingdom and european-union jurisdictions, you'd be able to request a copy of the contract and any other personal information under Article 15 of the UK GDPR or the GDPR respectively. For some specific types of contracts there might be other legislation which can assist you. E.g. see Regulation 12 of the Consumer Contracts (Information, Cancellation and Additional Charges) Regulations 2013 in relation to some types of consumer contracts, or Section 20A of the Housing Act 1988 in relation to most residential tenancy agreements.
I don't know whether similar provisions exist in the USA.

No
Contracts are private agreements.

Private as in "between private parties" but not necessarily private as in "secret". After all, courts arbitrate disputes over them in public.

@nick012000 I think the implication here is that being private means they don't appear in a public database by default.

@nick012000 Precisely, and two private parties can enter into a contract without notifying the government or any other centralized provider. (As opposed to, say, real estate where the deed must eventually be filed.) If nobody knows about it, it can't go in a database.
